# Scrapy. find a tag by its content

Tags: python, css, scrapy, css-selectors

How to find a tag by its content? This is how I find the necessary elements, but the structure on some pages is different and this does not always work.

```
yield {
            ...
            'Education': response.css('.provider-item:nth-child(3) .h2-style+ span::text').get(),
            'Training': response.css('.provider-item:nth-child(4) .h2-style+ span::text').get(),
            ...                
        }
```

Comment: Hi Sasha, could you make the question a bit more clear by adding some examples by showing expected outputs and where it goes wrong?

Comment: Hi @VishnuVS!
HTML code:
`<div class="listing-info listing-6 provider-item">
                        <span class="listing-h2 h2-style">Education</span>
                        <span itemprop="alumniOf" class="">A.B. in Economics with a minor in Asian Studies, <br>Occidental College<br>Masters in Chinese Medicine, Tai Hsuan Foundation</span>
                    </div>`

Comment: I found the heading 'Education':
`response.xpath("string(//span[contains(., 'Education')])").get()`

How to get the text below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the code sample

```
In [4]: i = response.xpath('.//span[contains(text(),"Education")]')

In [5]: i
Out[5]: [<Selector xpath='.//span[contains(text(),"Education")]' data='<span class="listing-h2 h2-style">Edu...'>]

In [6]: i.xpath('following-sibling::span[1]/text()').extract()
Out[6]:
['A.B. in Economics with a minor in Asian Studies, ',
 'Occidental College',
 'Masters in Chinese Medicine, Tai Hsuan Foundation']
```

Comment: Thanks. It works.
How to find this element through CSS Selectors?

Comment: check out the links [link1](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/Locators_table_1_0_2.pdf) [link2](https://cssselect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: I tried to use CSS: 
`response.css(span:contains("Education"))`
I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract all data points from `div.provider-item` tags at once you can try this (if "key" inside `span.h2` tag and `value` inside `span` tag with `itemprop` attribute

```
data = {}
for item in response.css("div.provider-item"):
    key = item.css("span.listing-h2.h2-style::text").extract_first()
    value = item.css("span[itemprop]::text").extract()
    #value = item.css("span::text").extract()[1:]
    data[key] = value
```

If each of `div.provider-item` tags have strictly 2 `span` tags you can try something like this:

```
data = {}
for item in response.css("div.provider-item"):
    key, value = item.css("span::text").extract()
    data[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer as the OP added a comment to the accepted answer stating he gets an error when implementing the solution with CSS selectors.

The right way to use CSS selectors to find elements that contains a fragment of text is:

```
response.css("span:contains('Education')").getall()
```

Note the use of double quotes for the overall selector string and single quotes for the text fragment inside it